Is the term "gaffer" used incorrectly and should "coordinator" be used instead?
This context comes from the movie "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood" It's a conversation between an actor Rick Dalton and his personal stunt double Cliff Booth who also doubles as his errand boy-cum-bodyguard. In this scene, Cliff's just run him to a set in the morning.
Cliff: "You talked to the stunt gaffer about me today? That way I'll know whether I'm working this week or not?"
Rick: "Yeah, Ahem, I've been meaning to tell you. The guy who gaffs this, he's best friend with Randy, the gaffer from The Green Hornet."
This definition comes from the Wikipedia:
In film and television crews, the gaffer or chief lighting technician is the head electrician, responsible for the execution (and sometimes the design) of the lighting plan for a production. The gaffer's assistant is the best boy electric.
What is even more confusing is that this is the line that Rick alters before the preceding context:
"I think the wind blew down my TV antenna last night, so while I piss-fart around with wardrobe, you might going home and fixing it?"
As you can see the usage of the word "gaffer" in the following conversation is especially confusing since the errand that Cliff (a stuntman) just received from Rick is something a "gaffer" who is an electrician would be more qualified to do.
I even though this was Ironinc on Cliffs part to say "did you talk to a stunt gaffer" after being given the and that he meant by it that he is the "guffer stuntman" (doing jobs of an electrician instead of working in his line of work). I don't think that's the case though. Is it a simple mistake on Tarantino's screenwriter?

The nloun gaffer is commonly used in such contexts. The verb form to gaff is virtually unknown (except maybe facetiously). You'll have to search hard to find any "mistakes" in anything any characters say in any of Tarantino's films!

I have no idea whether this is true, but it could mean not "person generally in charge of stunts," but "gaffer [with electrical/lighting senses] during a shoot devoted to stunts." Maybe stunt sequences are being filmed separately by a dedicated crew.

Note that gaffer is more like foreman / ganger (leader of a "crew") than manager. Tarantino would know this, and it's not impossible that he would deliberately have his character use the less likely term to convey a certain nuance.

@FumbleFingers I guess I assumed that a technical definition of the word applied and disregarded a more general one, which is : 3. Brit. the foreman or overseer of a group of workers.

In practice, since the movie is about Hollywood, and most of the characters are in the movie business, the "natural" interpretation of gaffer should indeed be the chief electrician. But obviously in the exact context (stuntman Cliff looking for work) it's the foreman of the entire stunt crew (who's definitely not gonna give Cliff any work, as I recall! :). As a Brit not working in movies, I barely notice that "misuse" of gaffer anyway, but it would never have been in the script if it weren't the lead-in to facetious The guy who gaffs this [movie] for comedic effect.

The dialog for 1978 film Hooper, a very famous film about stuntmen directed by former stuntman Hal Needham includes the line "Roger Deal: Look, you're the stunt gaffer. So, gaff." This may well be an influence. It's also found in some credits for older movies e.g. An American Werewolf in London (1981).

It's all "incorrect" usage - probably for comedic effect.
As you note, "gaffer" is properly used for the chief electrician.  But before that it was used for any foreman or supervisor.  For example in Tolkien "Lord of the Rings",  Sam talks about his "gaffer".  Sam is a gardener, and his gaffer is the head gardener.
So in the more general sense it might be reasonable to talk about the "stunt gaffer", as the senior stuntman (who arranges which stunt double will do which scene, etc)
The use of "gaff" as a verb is purely a joke.  "Gaffer" is actually a contraction of "godfather", and so to form a verb by removing "-er" is not correct.  It is surely just a joke.  "To gaff" would, apparently, mean to act as a senior worker.
